# Use command in file to enter mysql or other shell like environment

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, pipelining

Let’s say we have password stored in `/root/mysql-password`. Is there a way to connect to MySQL without manually coping password from that file and entering to `mysql -u root -p{passowrd}`?

For example something like this:

```
mysql -u root -p | {command} /root/mysql-password
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be create `/root/.my.cnf` file (don’t forget to `chmod 0600`) with this format:

```
[client]
user=root
password=rootpass
```

If you’re doing something and can’t have the file at `/root/.my.cnf`, you should be able to create it as `filename.cnf` and then invoke MySQL with `--defaults-file` like this:

```
mysql --defaults-file=/root/squirrellyfiles/filename.cnf
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So this is the only way? And there is no common "linux way" to do such things?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are asking. In Linux, you generally either have credentials in a flat config file (e.g. .my.cnf), a hashed or encrypted file, environment variables, through ssh keys, or a password prompt.  Passing the password through the command directly is very insecure.  Are you doing something where the defaults-file or .my.cnf doesn't work for you?

Comment: My password is in a file and whenever I wanted to connect to mysql I had to to "cat file/with/password" copy it and "mysql -u user -ppassword" I thought it is possible to automate manual coping part

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the preferred way of solving the particular problem, but the so-called "Linux way" would be to use backticks:

```
mysql -u root -p `cat /root/mysql-password`
```